# Figure.show works only for figures managed by pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

There's bug reported about using `matplotlib.pyplot` for matplotlib 3.5.1, so I am trying to use `matplotlib.figure.Figure` to draw figure and it work fine.

How can I view the graph in matplotlib for the `Figure` when I cannot call `plt.show`? Calling `fig.show` will give the following exception:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<module1>", line 23, in <module>
  File "C:\Software\Python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 2414, in show
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: Figure.show works only for figures managed by pyplot, normally created by pyplot.figure()
```

Demo code to show this issue:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 500)
y = np.sin(x**2)+np.cos(x)

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, label ='Line 1')
ax.plot(x, y - 0.6, label ='Line 2')
plt.show()      # It work, but I cannot use it for the scaling bug in matplotlib 3.5.1

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_subplot()
ax.plot(x, y, label ='Line 1')
ax.plot(x, y - 0.6, label ='Line 2')
fig.show()      # Get exception here
```

Comment: You misunderstood the issue. Matplotlib recommends to use object methods to PUT INK ON THE PAGE, and avoid the corresponding methods in the `pyplot` namespace, e.g., `ax.plot` vs `pyplot.plot` — but (BUT) all the convenience methods that are defined in the `pyplot` module are (almost) indispensable, like `plt.figure` or `plt.subplots`, because they take care of a lot of details that are necessary to hold the pieces together, as eloquently exposed in  [tdy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13138364/tdy) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75186822/2749397) below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear if your final goal is:

1. simply to use `fig.show()`
2. or to use `fig.show()` specifically with a raw `Figure()` object

---

**1. If you simply want to use `fig.show()`**

Then the first code block with `plt.subplots()` will work just fine by replacing `plt.show()` with `fig.show()`:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 4))  # if you use plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, label='Line 1')
ax.plot(x, y - 0.6, label='Line 2')
# plt.show()
fig.show()                              # fig.show() will work just fine
```

[image]

**2. If you specifically want to use a raw `Figure()` object**

Then the problem is that [it lacks a figure manager](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.show):

> If the figure was not created using [`pyplot.figure`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html#matplotlib.pyplot.figure), it will lack a [`FigureManagerBase`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/backend_bases_api.html#matplotlib.backend_bases.FigureManagerBase), and this method will raise an `AttributeError`.

That means you'd need to create the figure manager by hand, but it's not clear why you'd want to do this since you'd just be reproducing the `plt.subplots()` or `plt.figure()` methods.

---

Note that using `fig.show()` might give a backend warning (not error):

```
UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using module://matplotlib_inline.backend_inline,
  which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
```

This is a separate issue and is explained in more detail in the [`Figure.show`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.show) docs:

> **Warning:**
>
> This does not manage an GUI event loop. Consequently, the figure may only be shown briefly or not shown at all if you or your environment are not managing an event loop.
>
> Use cases for [`Figure.show`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.show) include running this from a GUI application (where there is persistently an event loop running) or from a shell, like IPython, that install an input hook to allow the interactive shell to accept input while the figure is also being shown and interactive. Some, but not all, GUI toolkits will register an input hook on import. See [Command prompt integration](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/interactive_guide.html#cp-integration) for more details.
>
> If you're in a shell without input hook integration or executing a python script, you should use [`pyplot.show`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.show.html#matplotlib.pyplot.show) with `block=True` instead, which takes care of starting and running the event loop for you.

Comment: The precondition is that I cannot use `matplotlib.pyplot` (plt) for there's bug for scaling issue, so also not `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 4))`. Although I didn't get the workaround, but lot of answer may help someone else, so I check to accept it here.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above, a raw `Figure` object does not have a figure manager. You can create one for your figure with the function `plt._backend_mod.new_figure_manager_given_figure`.

```
plt._backend_mod.new_figure_manager_given_figure(1, fig)
```

Where the number `1` is the figure number that will be assigned.

Comment: But OP said "The precondition is that I cannot use matplotlib.pyplot (plt)" so I'm not sure this helps him. And for anyone else, they should just use `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` and let matplotlib handle all the backend stuff.

Answer (score -1):

Replace this line:

```
fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
```

with this:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
```

and your code works.

Comment: The precondition is that I cannot use matplotlib.pyplot (plt) for there's bug for scaling issue.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that part.